# Как происходит связь браузера и сервера

Tags: сервер, запрос

После ввода в адресную строку, браузер отправляет запрос на сервер. Есть ли у сервера обратная связь с браузером? Что происходит если в момент отправки браузером запроса на сервер, закрыть вкладку, сервер как-то это узнает?

Comment: Обратной связи нет, но вы можете самостоятельно установить например websocket-соединение и следить за его состоянием

Comment: А касательно «в момент отправки браузером запроса на сервер, закрыть вкладку» вы это достоверно вряд ли узнаете. Есть шанс, что браузер успеет закрыть незавершённое соединение до окончания обработки запроса, но может и не успеть

Comment: правильно ли я понимаю, если вкладку в браузере закрыть то сервер примет запрос, но обратно отправлять не станет, так как уже "некуда"?

Comment: Зависит от задержек в сети. Есть вероятность, что сервер не успеет узнать, что отправлять уже некуда, и всё-таки отправит ответ в никуда

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> После ввода в адресную строку, браузер отправляет запрос на сервер.
> Есть ли у сервера обратная связь с браузером?

После отправки запроса как раз таки и происходит налаживание этой связи через SYN ACK

> Что происходит если в момент отправки браузером запроса на сервер,
> закрыть вкладку, сервер как-то это узнает?

Сервер отошлет пакет, не получит ответ и прекратит соединение